# Construct list of intervals consisting of midpoints of successive input values

Tags: python

I have a Python list consisting of data:

`[60, 120, 180, 240, 480]`

I need to calculate the intervals between the elements in the list and get the value in between the elements. For the above list, I'm looking for this output:

`[[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]`

The first and last values of the list is directly transferred, but the values in-between are obtained by the following method: e.g. for 60 and 120: (120 - 60 = 60 / 2 = 30 + 60 = 90)

I cannot work out how to do this in a simple pythonic fashion, and I have buried myself in `if`/`else` statements to solve it.

Comment: What is your `logic` to get the `intervals`?  It's not very clear.  And what's you've tried?

Comment: Can you explain, how you get 90, 150 and 210 in 0 index of output sub_lists?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in guys - I have tried to clarify the logic of the intervals and how to find the in-between/midpoints. - All numbers will be even, so no need to account for odds or floats. I need the midpoints twice to make it easier in the processing that happens afterwards in the script-code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shortest version that i can do

```
A = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]
B = []

for i in range(len(A)):
  if i == 0:
    B.append([A[i], (A[i] + A[i+1])//2])
  else:
    if(i < len(A)-1):
      B.append([B[i - 1][1], (A[i] + A[i+1])//2])
    else: 
      B.append([B[i - 1][1], A[i]])

print(B)
```

Comment: This is not returning the last pair-value: [360, 480]

Comment: If you add this outside the loop, the function seems to be complete: `B.append([B[-1][1], A[-1]])`

Comment: Sorry, it was generate annother intervals, i did a correction

Comment: I will award this as the most correct answer as you are not using any additional packages. (E. g. "Pairwise" as others do)

Comment: @skywalkerdk [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) is included in Python 3.10. If you're on an earlier version, you can [code it yourself](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) in four lines. In either case, there's no need to install any packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly simply with [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise). It's included in Python as of version 3.10, but if you're on an earlier version, you can get it from [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.pairwise) or [implement it yourself](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). (I also use [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean), which is a handy convenience even though it's trivial to reimplement.)

```
from itertools import pairwise
from statistics import mean

original = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]
midpoints = [mean(pair) for pair in pairwise(original)]
output = list(pairwise([original[0], *midpoints, original[-1]]))

print(output)
```

```
[(60, 90), (90, 150), (150, 210), (210, 360), (360, 480)]
```

Note that this outputs each pair as a tuple, rather than a list, as in your sample output. I think this is more idiomatic, and I would prefer it in my own code. However, if you'd prefer lists, it's a simple change:

```
from itertools import pairwise
from statistics import mean

original = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]
midpoints = [mean(pair) for pair in pairwise(original)]
output = [
    list(pair) for pair in pairwise([original[0], *midpoints, original[-1]])
]

print(output)
```

```
[[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]
```

Comment: (Of course I know you personally would prefer `map` to the list comp) ;-)

Comment: [Indeed](https://tio.run/##TY7BCgIxDETv/Yoct1Bhuy5SCn7J0kPUFQO2DW1B9OdrehC8vMPMZCb8bo@cjo5L74xUXlR3OMMT4@WGgB4@xBOCF4lqm1AbwM36oNW95Ai1YROdrhUoci4N4o5JKZSO7TQbsMuAEyyrYHVzEFcaDjZIJiJP48LAb1wmtAT8cP80pbhQGg/0/gU) :-)

Answer (score 1):

We can replace inner points by midpoints and then turn adjacent pairs into intervals:

```
a[1:-1] = map(mean, pairwise(a))
a[:] = pairwise(a)
```

As non-modifying function ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU7bCsIwDH3vV@SxhQnbHDIKfsnoQ3QdFtaupJ2iP18zh4h5OJCTnEt85tsSjn2kUiI6erhk4Qwz@suIgBpeLkoEzZRLWaKqAIdGGyUmWjykjJl5d03gfFwog7cYhBjtBC5kS3ecE6u0AB5kZxy02Re2OTSGKY9RbrIKvg1YoT5PZPNKYc/@O4pI7C9/GcOprqBpN@gZ2o6h62ujVClv)):

```
from itertools import pairwise
from statistics import mean

def intervals(a):
    a = a[:]
    a[1:-1] = map(mean, pairwise(a))
    return list(pairwise(a))

print(intervals([60, 120, 180, 240, 480]))
```

Output:

```
[(60, 90), (90, 150), (150, 210), (210, 360), (360, 480)]
```

The intervals are tuples instead of lists, but like CrazyChucky I think that tuples are more idiomatic for this (unless you actually have a need for them to be lists).

Answer (score -1):

```
x_list = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]

y = []
for i in range(len(x_list) - 1):
    y.append(int((x_list[i]+x_list[i+1])/2))
print(y)
z = [[x_list[0], y[0]]]
for i in range(0, len(y)-1):
    z.append([y[i], y[i+1]])
print(z)
z.append([y[-1], x_list[-1]])
print(z)
```

Try the above.
The first line printed are the midpoints, and the last row shows the final list.
It's a matter of understanding indices. There are probably faster ways to do it, but learning, it's better to iterate.

```
$ python example.py 
[90, 150, 210, 360]
[[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]
$
```

Comment: It missed the last item. Probably need to fiddle around with the last data item. Anyone can gladly edit and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following:

```py
def getIntervals(l):
    l2 = []
    l2.append(l[0])
    for i in range(0, len(l) - 1):
        l2.append((l[i] + l[i+1]) // 2)
    l2.append(l[-1])
    ret = []
    for i in range(len(l2) - 1):
        ret.append([l2[i], l2[i+1]])
    return ret
```

And then you can call it like this:

```py
x = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]
y = getIntervals(x)
print(y) # prints [[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]
```

Basically, you iterate through the list, and then you find the endpoints of each interval, and then you iterate through again and form the pairs of endpoints.

Answer (score -1):

Most pythonic way I can come up with:

```py
from itertools import pairwise  # python ≥3.10 only

l = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]
mid_points = map(lambda pair: sum(pair)//2, pairwise(l))  # [90, 150, 210, 360]
all_values = l[0], *mid_points, l[-1]  # pre/append 60 and 480 resp. to mid_points
# all_values: (60, 90, 150, 210, 360, 480)
list(pairwise(all_values))
# [(60, 90), (90, 150), (150, 210), (210, 360), (360, 480)]
```

If you don't have Python 3.10 you can emulate [`pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) with:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    # pairwise('ABCDEFG') --> AB BC CD DE EF FG
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solution written in function format (without needing to import anything):

Function:

```
def get_interval_list(my_list):

    interval_start = 0
    interval_end = 0
    interval_list = []

    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        if i == 0:
            interval_start = my_list[0]
        else:
            interval_start = interval_end

        if i == len(my_list)-1:
            interval_end = my_list[-1]
        else:
            current_num = my_list[i]
            next_num = my_list[i+1]
            interval_end = (current_num + next_num) / 2

        interval_list.append([int(interval_start), int(interval_end)])

    return interval_list
```

Function with commented explanations:

```
def get_interval_list(my_list):

    # variables (self explanatory... interval_list temporarily stores the interval start and 
    # end pair for each number being iterated through)
    interval_start = 0
    interval_end = 0
    interval_list = []

    # for loop iterates through the conditional statements for a number of times dependent on the 
    # length of my_list, finds interval_start and interval_end for each number in my_list, 
    # and then add each pair to interval_list
    for i in range(len(my_list)):

        # conditional statement checks if the current number is the first item in my_list, 
        # and if it is, assigns it to interval_start - if it isn't, the interval_end for the 
        # previous number will be the same as the interval_start for the 
        # current number (as per your requested output)
        if i == 0:
            interval_start = my_list[0]
        else:
            interval_start = interval_end

        # conditional statement checks if the current number is the last item in my_list,
        # and if it is, assigns it to interval_end - if it isn't, we calculate interval_end by
        # adding the current number and the next number in my_list and dividing by 2
        if i == len(my_list)-1:
            interval_end = my_list[-1]
        else:
            current_num = my_list[i]
            next_num = my_list[i+1]
            interval_end = (current_num + next_num) / 2

        # values of interval_start and interval_end are added as a pair to interval_list
        # (use int() here if you do not want your interval pairs to be returned as floats)
        interval_list.append([int(interval_start), int(interval_end)])

    return interval_list
```

Sample run using function above:

```
list_of_numbers = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]

print(get_interval_list(list_of_numbers))
```

Output:

```
[[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]
```

(Could be written more simply but I didn't want to sacrifice readability)

Just a side note: we don't need to use (120 - 60 = 60 / 2 = 30 + 60 = 90) to calculate the midpoints. There is a much simpler way; all we have to do is add the upper and lower limits and divide by 2 like so:
(60 + 120) / 2 = 90

(This mathematical method of finding midpoints works for any "range")

Answer (score -2):

This is the best i can come up with, but i'm really unsure if this is the simplest approach:

```
def generate_split_intervals(input_list):
    first_list_value = input_list[0]
    last_list_value = input_list[-1]
    return_list = []
    last_append = 0
    for idx, item in enumerate(input_list):
        if item == first_list_value:
            last_append = int(first_list_value + (abs(input_list[idx+1]-first_list_value)/2))
            return_list.append([first_list_value, last_append ])
        elif item == last_list_value:
            return_list.append([last_append, last_list_value])
        else:
            this_append = int(item + (abs(input_list[idx+1]-item)/2))
            return_list.append([last_append, this_append])
            last_append = this_append
    return return_list
```

Answer (score -2):

```
arr = [60, 120, 180, 240, 480]

def foo(x, i):
    return [(x[i] + x[max(0, i - 1)])//2,
            (x[i] + x[min(len(x) - 1, i + 1)])//2]
[foo(arr, i) for i in range(len(arr))]
# [[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]
```

OR

```
lz = zip((zip(arr, [arr[0]] + arr[:-1])),
         (zip(arr, arr[1:] + [arr[-1]])))
[[sum(a)//2, sum(b)//2] for a, b in lz]
# [[60, 90], [90, 150], [150, 210], [210, 360], [360, 480]]
```